# Cross section of a solid enclosed by surface and planes with another plane

Tags: geometry, volume, surfaces

I have a solid V enclosed by the surface (S) : $2x^2-y^2+2z^2-1=0$ and the planes $z = -1$ and $z=1$

I'm trying to calculate the area of the cross section obtained by cutting V with de $xz$ plane and the same thing but with the plane whose equation is $x-z = 0$.

I really don't know how to proceed, I tried to say that $y=0$ and rewrite (S) as $ 2x^2+2z^2-1=0$ but then I'm stuck.

Comment: I don't see how it's infinite, the solid V is finite as it's an hyperboloid cut between $z=-1$ and $z=1$. So if you cut a finite solid with a plane, it's should be either finite or $0$

Comment: Yes maybe, in either way, it's not infinite. It would be a logical nonsense to have the intersection between something finite and someting infinite to be infinite.

Comment: Then I don't get how this problem can be done. It's the only data I have

Comment: Yes I see your point, and you're right the solid is infinite. So I must have my surface wrong ... If you want to know more it's the problem 4 of this exam http://www.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/shared/admission/data/H31_suugaku_E.pdf

Comment: yeah, seems so. See my edited answer.

Comment: It looks to me like you got the rotation wrong. The surface in this question is not the correct $S_3$ from the exam problem.

Comment: I endlessly checked it, it seems that the rotation is fine, what's your answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first case, the required is shape is just circle with equation:$$ x^2 + z^2 = \cfrac{1}{2} $$ $\Rightarrow$ Radius $= \sqrt{\cfrac{1}{2}}$ $\Rightarrow$ Area $ = \cfrac{\pi}{2}$

For the second case, the area is unbounded, as the solid is not bounded sufficiently. This can be proved as follows:

Equation of solid: $ 2x^2 - y^2 + 2z^2 < 1 $ with constraint $ |z| \le 1 \Rightarrow z^2 \le 1 \Rightarrow |2x^2 - y^2| < 1$

Which would be hyperbolic sheet and the parameters of hyperbola would depend on value of $z$, on taking $z=1$, the equation of surface of intersection of the plane $z=1$ and the solid is obtained which is $y^2 - 2x^2 < 1$ which is unbounded. And as the plane $x = z$ extends infinitely in $y$ direction, the required cross sectional area is not finite.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, unfortunately I only have these constraints. The plane $x-z=0$ is supposed to be the tangent plane to the surface $x^2+2y^2-z^2=0$ at $A(2,0,2)$